# Why does alpha equivalence not apply to free variables?

Tags: lambda-calculus

It's mentioned in the book "Haskell programming from first principles" in the first chapter that one free variables don't have equivalence that is:

$$ \lambda x.xy \overset{\alpha-\text{eq.}}{\neq} \lambda x.xb$$

Could someone explain why this is so? What is the problem if we allow equivalence for free variables just like bound variables?

Comment: Hmm okay but that's only an issue if you choose a specific "y" to begin with @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: And on the contrary, *not* choosing “a specific $y$” is what binding the variable $y$ means.

Comment: Ah okay, now I understood. Thank you @sparusaurata